# Why does the function start before the button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I try to move a square down after a button has been pressed.
Why is the function executed before the button is pressed? What can I do about it?

I tried to use the .onclick and the .addEventListener methods.

```html
    <div class="block" id="blockColor"></div>
    <button id="btn">Move</button>
```

```js
    var pixel=0;
    function theLoop( i ){
      setTimeout( function() {
        document.getElementById("blockColor").style.top = pixel+"px";
        pixel++;
        if ( --i ){
          theLoop(i);
        } 
      }, 50)
    }
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener( "click", theLoop(50))
```

I expect the square moves down after the button is pressed, but right now it moves down without clicking.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should just give a reference to the function and not call it.

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", theLoop)
```

I hope it helps.

-- EDIT --
If you still want an argument, wrap the `theLoop` function like this:

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => theLoop( 50 ) )
```

Comment: This is right.  Whenever you have parens () after the name of a function in Javascript, that is the notation to immediately invoke the function and return the result.